# Paramiko's invoke_shell keeps closing the channel

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm new to paramiko, and I'm trying to create a basic honeypot server that provides a shell to the client side when they connect:

```
while True: 
            try: 
                client_socket, client_addr = honey_socket.accept() 
                transport = paramiko.Transport(client_socket)

                host_key = generate_or_load_host_key() 

                
                transport.add_server_key(host_key) 

                my_server = my_ssh_server()
                transport.start_server(server=my_server)   

                channel = transport.accept()  

                if channel is not None:  
                    if my_server.username in all_attempts:
                        if all_attempts[my_server.username] > 5:

                            imitate_shell(channel, my_server) 
                        else:
                            all_attempts[my_server.username] += 1  
                    else: 
                        all_attempts[my_server.username] = 1 
                else:
                    print("channel is none")

                count += 1 
                print(f"attempts: {all_attempts[my_server.username]}")  
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)  
                transport.close()  
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Server closing down") 
                break 
            finally:
                transport.close() 
                client_socket.close()
```

The honeypot is supposed to grant access after 5 attempts from the client, and then the function "imitate_shell" is called. Here's that function:

```
 print(f"IN THE SHELL, # OF ATTEMPTS: {all_attempts[my_server.username]}")

    user = my_server.username

    if not channel.closed: 

        print(channel.__repr__()) 
        shell = channel.invoke_shell()

        shell.send(f"{user}@honeypot:/$ ")

        buffer = ''

        while True:
            while not shell.recv_ready():
                time.sleep(0.1)
            input = shell.recv(1).decode('utf-8') 
            if input == '\n':
                if buffer == "exit":
                    break
                print({buffer})
                buffer = ''
            else:
                buffer += input

            print(input + '\n')

        shell.close()
```

I keep getting a "channel closed" exception, but I'm not sure why. Here are the overridden functions in the "my_ssh_server" class:

```
class my_ssh_server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event() 
        self.username = None
        self.password = None 
        
    
    # def check_auth_none(self, username): 
    #     return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL   


    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        print(f"the username: {username} and password: {password}")  
        return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL  
    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED 
    def check_channel_pty_request(self, channel, term, width, height, pixelwidth, pixelheight, modes):
        return True
    
    def check_channel_shell_request(self, channel):  
        return True 
    
    def check_channel_exec_request(self, channel, command):
        return True

# Function to generate or load the RSA host key
def generate_or_load_host_key():
    try:
        # Try to load the existing RSA key from the file
        host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename=HOST_KEY_FILE)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # If the file doesn't exist, generate a new RSA key
        host_key = paramiko.RSAKey.generate(bits=2048)
        # Save the generated key to the file
        host_key.write_private_key_file(HOST_KEY_FILE)

    return host_key
```

I'm expecting to be able to communicate with the client through the shell, but I think I'm doing something wrong. I've looked through the Paramiko documentation, but couldn't find any examples where the function is used on the server side.